# Accessing array elements and get specific data in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using an array to get the data from `SQL server` using `AFHTTPRequest` and `DCKeyValueObjectMapping` to parse the `JSON` data I get and put it as array

```
NSArray *chSpot = [parser parseArray:responseObject];
```

I have elements called `LocationLat` and `LocationLong` I want to access them and print them out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that chSpot has 3 objects, not sure what do you want to get (all or one). Anyway, you can get lat, long of spot at index 0 (first spot) by:

```
ChangingSpots *spot = [chSpot objectAtIndex:0];
float lat = spot.LocationLat;
float long = spot.LocationLong;
```

Comment: i still have a small error that is I declared the LocationLat and LocationLong as NSString how to change them with the compatible data type noting that the NSInteger and NSNumber are not acceptable

Comment: What do you want to change?. NSString -> float: `[str floatValue]`; float to NSString: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",floatValue]`